# Implode on codeigniter based active record result();

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have model that returned an object like this :

**MODEL**

```
public function getAllNama() {
    $this->db->select('nama');
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_user');
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
$data['users'] = $this->model_user->getAllNama();
$this->load->view('it_team/view_manual_entry', $data);
```

In view, I have a problem to manipulate it on html. 
In my case, I use auto completed based jquery like this

```
<input id="data_user"type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" 
    data-source='[<?=  ?>]'
    ">
```

Which is, in atribute `data-source` have a string format like this : `data-source="["nama1", "nama2"]"`

So, based that,

```
foreach(users as user){
   echo $user->nama; 
}
```

which is print user1user2, How can I pass this on data-source with suitable string format ?

I know implode, but i have try many ways, but still no success. Any solution it so appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure its `data-source="["nama1", "nama2"]"` and not `data-source="['nama1', 'nama2']"`? Also your foreach is missing `$` on variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php
    $names = '';
    foreach($users as $user){
       $names .= '"'.$user->nama.'",'; 
    }
    $names = trim($names, ','); ?>
    <input id="data_user"type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" 
        data-source='[<?php echo $names;?>]'>
```

Comment: You have one `"` extra there and you are missing `[]`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Can you give me a solution when user has selected one user, it will automatically displayed the all data of that user in another html which is Ajax can do it. What should I choose, focusOut() ?

Answer (score 0):

No need for all that, all you have to do is clean it in your controller, use `implode` as you mentioned, then send it to your view like this:

**Controller:**

```
public function getNamas(){
    $namas = $this->my_model->getAllNama();
    foreach ($namas as &$nama) {
        $nama = "'$nama->nama'";
    }
    $data['users'] = implode(",", $namas);
    $this->load->view('it_team/view_manual_entry', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<input id="data_user"
       type="text"
       data-provide="typeahead"
       data-items="4"
       data-source="[<?= $users ?>]"
>
```